# How to Find Dot Product of Two Lines (Opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv, dot-product

I'm working on a program that require me to find the angle between two lines. I have found all of the points coordinates of the lines, referenced into the 0,0 points, but i dont understand how to implement the dot product in Opencv to find the angle.

I use visual C++ using opencv library. I also found out that i can use cv::Mat::dot function to get dot product, but i can't find any good example. I can not understand the explanation in this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=dot#double%20Mat%3a%3adot%28InputArray%20m%29%20const).

Can anyone give me a good example? so i can understand how to use that function to find dot product of two lines. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have two vectors representing your lines, and call them `a` and `b` (of type `cv::Mat`) then the dot product is calculated as

```
double p = a.dot(b);
```

**Edit**
Example code, by comments from author.

```
float a[2] = {1.0, 2.0};
float b[2] = {3.0, 4.0};

cv::Mat AA(1,2,CV_32FC1,a);
cv::Mat BB(1,2,CV_32FC1,b);

cout << AA << endl;
cout << BB << endl;
cout << AA.dot(BB) << " should be equal to 11" << endl;
```

Comment: oke, thanks @kigurai. I have tried it, but the result of p is different with my classic calculation of a.b, where a(x1,y1) and b(x2,y2), a.b = x1*x2 + y1*y2. what i miss?

Comment: That is how it should work, yes. But it's hard to know what is wrong unless you post some code. What is the size of your vectors a and b?

Comment: my vectors are : a(-92,-131), b(57,-173). i create matrix of a & b using this code >> cv::Mat AA=cv::Mat(1,2,CV_32FC1,a) ; cv::Mat BB=cv::Mat(1,2,CV_32FC1,b). Then i execute double p=AA.dot(BB).. Anything wrong?

Comment: Not sure what type your `a` and `b` vectors are. I updated my answer with sample code that I confirmed works. I assumed a and b are float arrays. I am guessing your problem is in the data type of a and b.

Comment: Thanks @kigurai. my problem was so simple,i didn't define the size of the array variable. Now, it works so well. thanks to you & your great example.. :D

Answer (score -4):

Well, the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of two vectors A and B is defined as

`(length of A) * (length of B) * cos(angle)`

where `angle` represents the angle between the two vectors. So in order to find the angle between the two, first you have to find the dot product, then divide it by both the length of A and the length of B, then take the inverse cosine.

What this looks like in your case is something along these lines, assuming a and b are declared appropriately as `cv::Mat`s:

```
double dotprod = a.dot(b);
double angle = arccos(dotprod / (a.size().height * b.size().height))
```

Comment: thanks @Commander, i have tried your syntax, but i got NaN of my angle. so, what i miss? thanks :)

Comment: `a.size().height` is *not* going to be the length of `a`, same for `b`.